# Limit square property

Tags: calculus, limits

Is possible to show, without using $\lim_{x\to p}f(x)g(x)=\lim_{x\to p}f(x)\cdot\lim_{x\to p}g(x)$, and without using that $f(x)=x^2$ is continuous, that  $$\lim_{x\to p}[f(x)]^2=[\lim_{x\to p}f(x)]^2?$$

Comment: Have you tried a proof by induction?

Comment: Where does induction fits here?

Comment: You can define your proof as a property that you need to show. And then use induction to show that the property is true for n>1. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Let $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to p} f(x) = L$. Fix $\epsilon > 0$. Choose $\delta$ such that if $|x-p| < \delta$,
$$
|f(x)-L| < \min\left\{1,\frac{\epsilon}{2(|L|+1)}\right\}.
$$
Note that if $|f(x)-L| < 1$, then $|f(x)| < 1 + |L|$. Then, for $|x-p|<\delta$,
\begin{align*}
\left|f(x)^2-L^2\right| &= \left|f(x)^2 - Lf(x) + Lf(x) - L^2\right|\\
&\leq |f(x)||f(x) - L| + |L||f(x) - L|\\
&< (|L|+1) \frac{\epsilon}{2(|L|+1)} + (|L|+1)\frac{\epsilon}{2(|L|+1)}\\
&= \epsilon.
\end{align*}